# Integration of $\int \frac{\cos2x}{\cos^2x} \ dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

From the integral $$\int \frac{\cos2x}{\cos^2x} \ dx$$ I managed to get $$\int \frac{2\cos2x}{\cos2x+1}\ dx $$ How do I simplify it further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

According to André Nicolas we have
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\cos 2x}{\cos^2 x}\,dx&=\int\frac{2\cos^2 x-1}{\cos^2 x}\,dx=\int(2-\sec^2 x)\,dx
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\cos 2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$$